# spoj treat for cows DP getting wrong answer?

Tags: c++, c

why am i getting wrong answer . I have used DP and filling the table bottom up.

http://www.spoj.com/problems/TRT/

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dp[i][i]=n*a[i];
    }

    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            dp[i][j]=max((i+1)*a[i]+dp[i+1][j],dp[i][j-1]+(i+1)*a[j]);//(i+1) is the age

        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",dp[0][n-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The age will not be i+1.  It will be n+i-j.

```
dp[i][j] = max(  (n+i-j)*a[i]+dp[i+1][j],  dp[i][j-1] + (n+i-j)*a[j] );
```